# Typing the Int Value, The Next String to Input Is Skipped

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I Have a Simple Problem, When I Type the Int Value, The Next String to Input Is Skipped.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class YOW{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Info= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Your:");
    String Var1=Info.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Your :");
    String Var2=Info.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Your :");
    String Var3=Info.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Your :");
    int Var4=Info.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Your:");
    String Var5=Info.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your :");
    String Var6=Info.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Your");
    String Var7=Info.nextLine();

    
System.out.print("Information\n"+"\n"+Var1+"\n"+Var2+"\n"+Var3+"\n"+Var4+"\n"+Var5+"\n"+Var6+"\n"+Var7);

}
    
}
```

When I Type the Int Value, The Next String to Input Is Skipped:

[image: When I Type the Int Value, The Next String to Input Is Skipped.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Plese give the input you entered

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the input into the question as text.

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with an upper case letter; methods and variables start with lower case letters.